# Changes made to cities during Stormcloak civil war quests

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

What changes are made to Falkreath Hold, The Reach, Hjaalmarch and Haffingar after I complete the civil war quests siding with the Stormcloaks ?

First of all, I'm a deep role-player, so every detail is important, specially when it comes to dialogue.

Example:

> When I finished the Battle for Whiterun Quest, a option of dialogue was added to a lot of 
> NPCs regarding how they feel about the Stormcloaks in the city, some NPCs changed, like 
> new Jarl, Steward and Housecarl, and Heismkr can't enter his house anymore and he nows
> sleep on a tent.

That's what I want to know, and more if you can give me, about each of the cities I mentioned on the first paragraph.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the wiki? Your question is rather specific, and has a huge answer, and would require people to type out a lot. (I also do not understand the deep roleplaying remark, as a roleplayer, why would you want to know the answers to your ingame actions beforehand?).

Comment: How to look at the wiki ? >_> I'm new here, I tried checking Wikia and UESP and searching on google and here. About my RP remark, I want to know if there is something that will happen so I can check, otherwise, I won't waste my time talking with everybody before and later, and most people say the differences aren't major on the civil war questline, and I think It is, specially Whiterun Mission and the last one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- If you've been made thane in a hold that changes hands later, you will have to become thane again.
- Rulers and stewards of captured holds will be moved to either Solitude castle (Stormcloaks line) or Winterhold csatle (Empire line).
- People who have particular interest in the conflict may have new dialogue and their disposition may change, examples of these are non-Nords in Winterhold, Talos priesthood and some civilians.
- Some minor structural damage to the captured capital.
- The farmer who gives you the repeatable quests to harvest produce in Whiterun will die and 2 houses will become inaccessible (the farmer's and Heimskr's) during the battle for Whiterun.